# Dump data from python cron job to google spreadsheets

Tags: python, csv, cron, google-api-python-client

I am creating a CSV which contains the report as a result of a cronjob. I want to share this CSV via Google spreadsheets - the report itself is versioned, so I would just dump the CSV contents into the same worksheet in the same spreadsheet each and every single time.

I have found [gspread](https://github.com/burnash/gspread) which looked very promising but unfortunately gives me `NoValidUrlKeyFound` Errors. The Python example for interacting with the Spreadsheets API v4 (to be found [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/python?utm_campaign=web%20fundamentals_discussion_sheetsapi_061516&utm_source=appdev&utm_medium=blog)) requires interactivity because of the OAuth flow.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Ideally I would just do:

```
client = spreadsheet.client(credential_file)
client.open_spreadheet(url_or_something).open_worksheet(0).dump(csv)
print("Done")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer in a Github issue:

Using gspread, follow the [official guide](https://github.com/burnash/gspread#readme) to [receive an oauth token](http://gspread.readthedocs.org/en/latest/oauth2.html). You will end up with a JSON file holding the credentials.

In order to access a spreadsheet with these credentials however, you need to share the spreadsheet with the account represented by them. In the JSON file there is a property `client_email`. Share the document with that e-mail address and voila, you'll be able to open it!